# Divs overlaps when animating with Dojo toolkit

Tags: dojo

I am learning Animation with Dojo Toolkit. I am trying to animate a div. I have created two div's upper and lower div. when i create animation object for upper div, lower div is moving to the upper div space and overlapping each other. how do i prevent lower div moving to upper div place while animating upper div.

the code i am trying to solve is here.

jsfiddleDOTnet/Mostwanted_cJ/26rhq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, in order to make a DOM node moveable like in the animation, they give it the following inline CSS: `position: absolute`. Due to this, it will be "removed" from the normal flow, so your second div will not be aware of the first one, so they will overlap.

To solve this problem, you should wrap your `#box1` inside a container-div which has `position: relative`. Your `#box2` will be aware of the container and your `#box1` is relatively positioned towards your container. The full HTML would be:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id='box1'></div>
</div>
<div id='box2'></div>
```

And the CSS would be:

```css
#box1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
#box2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #686868;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
}
```

As you can see I also slightly changed the `height`. You need to give your container a height so that `#box2` will be positioned correctly. Now, because you give the container a `height`, you can change the `height` of `#box1` into `100%`. Because it's relative towards the container, `100%` is equal to `300px`.

I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/26rhq/1/).

Comment: All the books for Dojo is outdated. And tutorials on Dojo site is not complete and its hard to learn from API Reference. Will you please point me to some best and userfull resources for DOjo 1.9 complete tutorial for begginer

Comment: I usually use the reference guide of Dojo and the tutorial section of the Dojo website/Sitepen. It isn't complete, but it introduces you to the basics and from there you should be able to solve if by yourself (using the API documentation and the reference guide).
However, this issue is related to CSS and not to Dojo.